# Replication and CDC SQL 2008r2 what causes some replicated tables to drop CDC?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication, change-data-capture

Transactional replication from SQL 2005 into SQL 2008r2.  CDC established on SQL 2008r2 side.  Each day, from 2 to 4 of these tables lose their CDC settings (ie. is_tracked_by_cdc in sys.tables moves from 1 to 0 and all CDC objects for that table are gone)  What could be causing this and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with the vendor, and other than initial set up issues, this was only happening on table where there is a nightly sync that supercedes the daily changes.  i.e. replication and cdc run during the day to capture near real time changes, during nightly batch, the table is truncated and recalculated.  The gave me a methodology to detect when this is taking place, so that I can cleanly turn off CDC and restart when the process is complete.